# Fixing the autocomplete for :Rcontroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, vim-plugin

Anyone using the Rails plugin?

`:Rcontroller adm<tab>`, which triggers some kind of auto-complete, always returns `:Rcontroller admin/admins`.

This is because, I've got a file called `admins_controller.rb` in the `admin` dir.

I need it to return `:Rcontroller admin/` instead.

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

```
:help wildmode
```

This allows you to tweak the completion behaviour, which also effects :RController. I personally have

```
 set wildmode=longest:full
```

in my .vimrc. This makes it only complete up to the longest match and shows a 'menu' with the remaining options.

I believe you have to do a 'set wildmenu' as well for this to function.

Comment: Thanks! `set wildmode=list:longest,list:full` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution but a workaround : in Command Mode (or Insert mode) you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to delete the last word.

So you can auto complete to `:Rcontroller admin/admin` and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

Comment: I'd like to do this with as few keys as possible

Comment: Fair enough, that being said I am not sure I understand why you want to get `:Rcontroller admin/` The comamnd :Rcontroller is supposed to open a "controller.rb" file and not a directory. If you need to open another controller in that directory, like foo_controller you should try to type `:Rcontroller foo`. I guess you have two types of contoller, like "admin/user_controller.rb" for admin and "user_controller.rb" for normal user ?

Comment: Sometimes, I'd like to do `:Rcontroller adm<tab>`, which returns `:Rcontroller admin/`, then `:Rcontroller admin/foo<tab>`, which returns `:Rcontroller admin/foobar`. Instead of doing: `:Rcontroller adm<tab>ctrl+wfoo<tab>`